# SWT Raise messageBox outside from the program main display

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swt

I'm tring to Raise MessageBox without any contact to the main display.
I tried:

```
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 MessageBox errorMessage = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                 errorMessage.setText("File Download");
                 errorMessage.setMessage("The machine is now downloading files from the server .\n" +
                         "Please wait until this process is done and do not close the machine widow.\n");
                 errorMessage.open();

             }
            });
```

and also tried with :

```
Display display = new Display();
```

But Still the MessageBox was raised after the download of the files (I want it to be Separated)

(With the Display display = new Display(); i got exception)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do mean by 'without any contact to the main display'?

Comment: I want that the MessageBox Will appear and the rest of The program will continue running (like in different Threads). (Now The MessageBox appear just after the logic)